# Выдача результатов в том же порядке что и в IN()

Tags: php, mysql

Есть такой запрос:

```
$translit = $DB->select("SELECT * FROM 'p_CatalogItem' WHERE 'ID' IN (17,19,20,18)");
```

Но MySQL строки с результатами возвращает совсем в другом порядке:

> 17,18,19,20

т.е. просто по возрастанию. А мне нужно, чтобы было ровно так же, как в запросе.
Это возможно?

Или если запрос выглядит вот так:

```
$translit = $DB->select("SELECT * FROM p_CatalogItem WHERE ID IN (?a)", $dopColors);
```

т.е. вместо конкретных цифр переменная, которая эти цифры и содержит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо сделать так.

С помощью `ORDER BY`.

> ORDER BY field(`field name`, `array`)

```
$translit =  $DB->select("SELECT * FROM 'p_CatalogItem' WHERE 'ID' IN (17,19,20,18)" ORDER BY field(ID, 17,19,20,18));
```

Вот вариант с переменной. Так выглядит запрос.

```
$translit = $DB->select("SELECT * FROM p_CatalogItem WHERE ID IN (?a) ORDER BY field(ID, ?a)", $dopColors);
```

Comment: Точно, спасибо. А если запрос выглядит так?
$translit =  $DB->select("SELECT *
   FROM `p_CatalogItem` WHERE `ID` IN (?a)", $dopColors);
т.е. те конкретные цифры, а массим

Comment: Дайте все в вопросе пож. а не в комментариях.

Comment: @Regent Принимаю ваше мнение, спасибо.

Comment: @RazGalstyan
Во втором варианте нет ошибки с кавычками?
Вот так кажется должно быть:


$translit = $DB->select("SELECT * FROM p_CatalogItem WHERE ID IN (?a), $dopColors  ORDER BY field(ID, ?a)", $dopColors);
хотя все равно NULL

Comment: @Mit5x Да это я увидел, и исправил уже.